# origin is not allowed by access-control-allow-originのエラーについて

Tags: monaca, jquery, ajax

monacaとniftymbaasを使ってアプリを作成しています。

アプリの作成を進めるにあたりエラーが発生するようになりました。
エラー内容としては、origin is not allowed by access-control-allow-originがアラートとして何度も発生してしまいます。
私のアプリはajaxを使っていまして、これが悪さをしているのではないかと思っています。
その対応として、jsonp, jQueryのプラグインであるjquery.xdomainajax.jsなどを使ってみましたが、エラーの発生は直ることができませんでした。

私のプログラムの書き方が悪かったのもあると思いますが、上記の手段以外でエラーが発生しない方法はあるのでしょうか？

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: そのエラーに対する理想的な対応はアクセス先が適切な `Access-Control-*` ヘッダを返すようにすることです。`jquery.xdomainajax.js` は少々強引な方法ですし、JSONPは結局アクセス先が対応していないといけません。いずれにしてもどんなサーバーにAjax通信しようとしているのか、あるいは問題のJavascriptコードを見せてもらわないと、どこに問題があるのか、どんな策があるのかを提示するのは難しいかと思います。

Comment: Monacaデバッガーですか？ それとも、ビルドしたアプリで発生していますか？ Monacaデバッガー5系 + Crosswalkだと、そのエラーが発生します。 Monacaデバッガー6系であれば、そのエラーは出なくなっていると思います。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。デバッガーとビルドでエラーが発生しております。デバッガーは5系を使ってますので、エラーの発生原因となっているのがわかりました。ビルドの場合はなぜ発生するのでしょうか？

Comment: ビルドで出るようであれば、InAppUpdaterプラグインなど、ajaxを呼び出すファイルが書き換え可能な領域に保存されている、config.xmlのallow-navigationやallow-intentの設定、index.htmlで指定しているContent-Securiy-Policyの設定などでしょうか。それ以上は、コードを見ないと分からないです